# Feature Request to Include Gravatar URL for Users API

Tags: feature-request

The result set for the users API does not return the URL for the user's Gravatar.

For reference: http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/help/method?method=users

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The gravatar url can be calculated from the email hash.

```
string gravatarUrl = "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/" + emailHash + "?d=identicon&r=PG";
```

More [gravatar info](http://en.gravatar.com/site/implement/url).

Comment: Or, include the size to get a larger icon: `?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG`

Comment: r=PG ? or r=G ?

Comment: That's up to you. ;)

Answer (score 3):

As part of the response you get the email hash, which you can use to construct the proper request to Gravatar:

```
  "email_hash": {
    "description": "email hash, suitable for fetching a gravatar",
    "values": "string"
  },
```